# How to ask a question repeatedly until I get the right answer as a character

Tags: java, loops, char

I should ask "choose" and the user should type a b or c if he types somehting else, it should repeat the question. I don't even understand how I do that and then I have another problem: Later I should print out the chosen sort of coffee but because the "eingabe" is in a while or if body it can't be recognized when I want to use it later. How do I solve this problem? Or should I use another loop anyway? And is character even the right type to use here?
Thx in advance.

```
    while(eingabe != 'a' || eingabe != 'b' || eingabe ||'c') {
        Out.println("Bitte auswaehlen: ");
        char eingabe = in.readChar();
    }
        
    Out.print("Gewaehlt ");
    if (eingabe == 'a') Out.print("CAPPUCCINO");
    if (eingabe == 'b') Out.print("MOKKA");
    if (eingabe == 'c') Out.print("VERLAENGERTER");
    Out.print(" !");
}
```

Comment: declare the `char eingabe = in.readChar();` outside of the while loop

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned before you should declare it outside the loop. And you mistyped in the loop when check c:

```
    char eingabe = '';
    while(eingabe != 'a' && eingabe != 'b' && eingabe != 'c') {
        Out.println("Bitte auswaehlen: ");
        eingabe = in.readChar();
    }
        
    Out.print("Gewaehlt ");
    if (eingabe == 'a') Out.print("CAPPUCCINO");
    if (eingabe == 'b') Out.print("MOKKA");
    if (eingabe == 'c') Out.print("VERLAENGERTER");
    Out.print(" !");
```

Comment: Hey, thank you, I fixed my mistakes but there's still 1 thing that doesn't work out. char eingabe = ''; doesn't work because "error: empty character literal"

Comment: You should then use a character which will not accepted by your code (not a, b or c).

Answer (score 1):

Your `eingabe` variable should be defined outside of the loop, so the rest of your code can access it. Just be careful not to initialise it with a value checked for in the condition, or even better use a do-while instead.

I switched your code to use regular System.in and System.out, as I do not know what those in and Out are. Last but not least, your output condition was wrong, you should ask again if the value is is different from all expected values, not if differend from any (which is always true):

```
        String eingabe;
        try (final InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in)) {
            try (final BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(isr)) {
                do {
                    System.out.println("Bitte auswaehlen: ");
                    eingabe = in.readLine();
                } while (!"a".equals(eingabe) && !"b".equals(eingabe) && !"c".equals(eingabe));
            }
        }

        System.out.print("Gewaehlt ");
        switch (eingabe) {
        case "a" -> System.out.print("CAPPUCCINO");
        case "b" -> System.out.print("MOKKA");
        case "c" -> System.out.print("VERLAENGERTER");
        default -> throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected eingabe: " + eingabe);
        }
        System.out.print(" !");
```

Edit: reading directly characters from stdin is quite raw, you get a second "Bitte auswaehlen: " when it reads the '\n' character. You would want to get a proper `BufferedReader` to cleanly read stdin line by line

Comment: This works, thx a lot. Yes, I didn't think this all through with using && or || but it's harder when it doesn't compile and you can't test if your code makes sense or not.

Comment: Actually it prints out twice when it repeats it. The 1st time it prints it out only once as it should do. Bitte auswaehlen: 
d
Bitte auswaehlen: 
Bitte auswaehlen: 
f
Bitte auswaehlen: 
Bitte auswaehlen:  Do you know why this could be?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a problem in your expression `eingabe != 'a' || eingabe != 'b' || eingabe ||'c'`. Maybe you meant `eingabe != 'a' || eingabe != 'b' || eingabe != 'c'`. I think in order to continue loop when user types something else, you need to use `&&` instead of `||`. A do while loop is ideal for your use case:

```java
char eingabe;
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
do {
    System.out.println("Bitte auswaehlen: ");
    eingabe = in.next().toCharArray()[0];
} while (eingabe != 'a' && eingabe != 'b' && eingabe != 'c');
```